# How to delete row with rowdeleting event?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

this is my .cs code

```
 protected void Gridview1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
 Gridview1.DeleteRow(e.RowIndex);
 Gridview1.DataBind();
}
```

and this is my source code for

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Horizontal" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks="True">
            <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField CancelText="İptal" DeleteText="Sil" EditText="Düzenle" InsertText="Yerleştir" SelectText="Seç" ShowEditButton="True" UpdateText="Güncelle" />
                <asp:CommandField CancelText="İptal" DeleteText="Sil" EditText="Düzenle" InsertText="Yerleştir" SelectText="Seç" ShowDeleteButton="True" UpdateText="Güncelle" />
            </Columns>
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" ForeColor="Black" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#333333" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CC3333" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F7F7F7" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4B4B4B" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E5E5E5" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#242121" />
        </asp:GridView>
```

i have to delete row when i select rowdeleting but i dont know how to

Edit : i made .cs like this

```
        protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Delete From adminler (admin_no,admin_kullanici_adi,admin_sifre,admin_email,admin_adi,admin_soyadi)");
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

when i press delete button it deletes all of the datas and when i reload the page the datas coming back so its not saving them

Comment: Have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/editing-data-using-asp-net-gridview-control). It covers all the basics of GridView editing and updating.

Comment: Creating the `SqlCommand` alone is not enough. You also need to execute it. And heed @VDWWD's advice.

Comment: @VDWWD That tutorial is pretty cool im going to use them to updating and editing , but theres not rowdeleting thats to important one for now.

Comment: @MarkusDeibel i executed it but still problems is same

Answer (score 0):

```
    bunu dene   



     <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"  DataKeyNames="ID" /// Burası önemli tablodaki ıdenty id yi yaz 
CellPadding="4" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Horizontal" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks="True">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:CommandField CancelText="İptal" DeleteText="Sil" EditText="Düzenle" InsertText="Yerleştir" SelectText="Seç" ShowEditButton="True" UpdateText="Güncelle" />
                        <asp:CommandField CancelText="İptal" DeleteText="Sil" EditText="Düzenle" InsertText="Yerleştir" SelectText="Seç" ShowDeleteButton="True" UpdateText="Güncelle" />
                    </Columns>
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" ForeColor="Black" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#333333" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CC3333" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F7F7F7" />
                    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4B4B4B" />
                    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E5E5E5" />
                    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#242121" />
                </asp:GridView>



          protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
            {
                GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Delete From adminler where ID=@ID ");
        cmd.AddWithValue("@ID",int.parse(GridView1.DataKeys[ID].Value))// yukarıda datakey girdiğin tablonun identy si yani
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
```